# C programming pointer pre-fix post-fix

Tags: c, pointers

I was having some problem when trying to understand pointer in C programming.

```
struct student {
int age;
char *name;
};

int main()
{
    struct student b[3] = { 18, "Peter", 19, "Mary", 20, "John" };
    struct student *p = b;

    printf("%d\n", ++p->age);
    printf("%s\n", (*p).name);
    printf("%c\n", *p->name - 1);
    printf("%c\n", *++p->name);
    printf("%c\n", *p++->name);
    printf("%c\n", *(++p)->name);
    return 0;
}
```

The outputs that I am getting from visual studio were:

```
19
Peter
0
e
e
J
```

For the first 3 lines I understand how it work. However, at `*++p->name` how come it's 'e'. I thought the pointer already pointing at Mary and it should be 'a' and the following should be 'a' as well since it's post-fix. Then as for `*(++p)->name`, let's say the previous line returning me 'e', how it skipped Mary and printed out 'J'.

I was tasked to write the output on paper without running the program so I would like to know why. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For addressing operations "Start with the suffix, proceed with the prefix, and read both sets from the inside out." Except where precedence is overridden by parens, which work the same way they do with other operators.

So `*x->y` is interpreted as treating `x` as a `->` pointer to struct, looking up its `y` member, then treating that as a pointer and `*` dereferencing that to get the final value.

Conversely, `(*x)->y` is interpreted as treating `x` as a pointer to a pointef to struct, `*` dereferencing it to get a pointer to struct, and then `->` retrieving the `y` member thereof.

Note that [] is a suffix operator too. So`*x[3]->y` retrieves the third pointer-to-struct, gets y from that, and then dereferences.

__Useful tip:_ The syntax and precedence for C declarations is exactly the same as for C addressing. So `int (*x)[4];` is a pointer to an array of four ints, whereas `int *x[4];` is an array of 4 pointers to ints.

(I wrote a simple recursive-descent parser for C declarations, many years ago, which would convert them into phrases of this sort. As any old-school hacker would, I called it the C EXplainer, or CEX, with the obvious pronunciation.)

Answer (score 0):

`*++p->name` equivalent to `*(++(p->name))`.

At that point, `p` is still pointing to the first element of `b` so its contents are `{ 18, "Peter" }`.

It takes the `name` pointer, applies the prefix increment to it and the expression evaluates to a pointer to the second character of `"Peter"`. Finally the dereferencing operator gives the character `'e'`.

---

At `*(++p)->name`, `p` is pointing to the last element of `b` (after the increment) so its contents are `{ 20, "John" }`.

That takes the `name` pointer and dereferences it to give us the first character of `"John"` which is `'J'`.

**Edit:** it may be helpful for you to print out pointer values after each `printf` to help you understand the output.

Comment: I think I get it already. The *p++->name will shift my pointer pointing to Mary and the next *(++p)->name will be pointing to John. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
struct student b[3] = { 18, "Peter", 19, "Mary", 20, "John" };
```

Creates an array of `struct student` with three elements that, depending on compiler and padding, will have a `sizeof` 12-16 chars (x86_64) or 8-16 chars (x86) made up of `4-bytes` (int) and `8-bytes` (char *) (4-bytes on x86) and will have a memory layout of something like (for example purposes):

```
 int  char*
+----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+
|age |name*   |age |name*   |age |name*   |
+----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+
^
p
```

The individual string literals (`"Peter", "Mary", "John"`) are created in memory and a pointer to each string literal is stored as `name` in individual elements of the struct.

When you use the `->` operator, it is a dereference for the struct. Using the pre-increment operator on `p->age`, you get the next age element in array `b`, but the pointer address `p` is unchanged:

```
printf("%d\n", ++p->age);

+----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+
|age |name*   |age |name*   |age |name*   |
+----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+
^              ^
p              ++p->age

19
```

Dereferencing `p` and using the `'.'` (dot) operator, you print the name associated with the current element in `b`:

```
printf("%s\n", (*p).name);

Peter
```

When you subtract `1` from `*p->name` you are decrementing a character pointer by `1` which leaves you in *no-mans-land* at an address in memory somewhere before the string literal "Peter".

```
printf("%c\n", *p->name - 1);

+----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+
|age |name*   |age |name*   |age |name*   |
+----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+
^     \
p      Peter (string literal in memory)
      ^
      p->name - 1
0
```

When you dereference then pre-increment, (you are incrementing the pointer `p->name`) you move one char forward in the string literal "Peter":

```
printf("%c\n", *++p->name);

+----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+
|age |name*   |age |name*   |age |name*   |
+----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+
^     \
p      Peter
        ^
        ++p->name
e
```

When you next dereference, then post-increment, you are printing the same character and then advancing the pointer to the second element in `b`:

```
printf("%c\n", *p++->name);

+----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+
|age |name*   |age |name*   |age |name*   |
+----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+
^     \
p      Peter
        ^
        p->name
e

+----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+
|age |name*   |age |name*   |age |name*   |
+----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+
              ^
              p
```

Finally by operator precedence, you pre-increment the pointer (advancing the pointer to the third element in `b`) and then derefernce the pointer `p->name` pointing to `J`:

```
printf("%c\n", *(++p)->name);

+----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+
|age |name*   |age |name*   |age |name*   |
+----+--------+----+--------+----+--------+
                            ^     \
                            p      John
                                   ^
                                   p->name
J
```